# Diophantus again; not to say Pell.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a way to solve the second degree Diophantine equation in two variables $ax^{2} -ny^{2} = b$  $(1)$ where  a and b are known and n is a parameter; all solutions x= f(n) and y = f(n) ?  For example take a =1 and b =1 and solve (1) over the integers, with solutions function of n.

Comment: As usual you can write down all rational solutions if you have one. If you should want integral solutions, the class group will make itself heard.